# why in dict when we have have the same values with different keys name then why it picks one compared with another

Tags: python-3.x

```
   >>> votes ={}
    >>> votes["maddy"]=6
    >>> votes["katty"]=6
    >>> votes


   {'maddy': 6, 'katty': 6}
    >>> print(max(votes.items(), key = lambda k:k[1]))
    ('maddy', 6)
    >>> votes["jackie"]=1
    >>> votes
    {'maddy': 6, 'katty': 6, 'jackie': 1}
    >>> votes["kavi"]=1
    >>> votes
    {'maddy': 6, 'katty': 6, 'jackie': 1, 'kavi': 1}
    >>> print(min(votes.items(), key = lambda k:k[1]))
    ('jackie', 1)
    >>>
```

I understand that whatever items we insert first with max values will be 
    considered as max votes as shown below but what if i need the max values 
    as 
     katty key with values as 6 which is inserted after maddy key with same 
    value 6 ?

```
    print(max(votes.items(), key = lambda k:k[1]))
 ('maddy', 6)

expected output is 
Katty , 6
```

Comment: So if the keys are same, you want the key-value pair which is smaller in lexicographical ordeR?

Comment: in above case keys are not same .. maddy is 1 key and katty is 1 key where as values are same  so objective is to get the max votes in key value pair but it ll take as maddy as i had inserted first in dict but not the katty .. question is why such behaviour?

Comment: am suspecting its an python behavior which ever we insert the first key will be taken then highest preference..but not the second key with same value... so what if i need the second key value is my question.?

Comment: get the max value, iterate through the dict, and pick the last key where the value is found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`max` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

> If multiple items are maximal, the function returns the first one encountered.

Moreover, your code also depends on the order of elements returned by `.items()`. The `dict` guarantees the insertion order since Python3.7 (read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values)). If your version is lower than 3.7 and you want to keep the elements insertion order, you can use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

If you want to return the latest element with max / min value, you can explicitly specify the order in the key:

```
In [1]: votes = {'maddy': 6, 'katty': 6}

In [2]: max(votes.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
Out[2]: ('maddy', 6)

In [3]: max(enumerate(votes.items()), key=lambda x: (x[1][1], x[0]))
Out[3]: (1, ('katty', 6))

In [4]: max(enumerate(votes.items()), key=lambda x: (x[1][1], x[0]))[1]
Out[4]: ('katty', 6)
```

Note that for `min` you will need to negate the index in the key function to retrieve the latest element. This is required to make element with index, say, 3 lower than element with index 2. After negating indices you will compare -3 with -2 and -3 will be lower than -2, and therefore `min` will return the element with higher index:

```
In [5]: votes = {'maddy': 6, 'katty': 6, 'a': 1, 'b': 1}

In [6]: min(enumerate(votes.items()), key=lambda x: (x[1][1], -x[0]))[1]
Out[6]: ('b', 1)
```

Or you can just reverse the order of items:

```
In [7]: max(reversed(list(votes.items())), key=lambda x: x[1])
Out[7]: ('katty', 6)
```

Comment: Thank you so much awesoon.. it works what i wanted the latest key with same value.. giving u upvotes soon